# Using jQuery to remove an option from a drop down list?

Tags: jquery, debugging, list, drop-down-menu

I have used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert(jQuery('#FormField_11').html());
    jQuery("#FormField_11 option[value='Afghanistan']").remove();
});
```

and it is giving me the alert message, but the value is not removed from the dropdownlist.

Is there a visible error in my code?
Can you you please advise me on how to implement this correctly?

Comment: Please provide more information, it works perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/LLpA5/. If we cannot replicate the problem, we are not able to help you.

Comment: check inspector console (f12)

Answer (score 0):

Above code also works fine but just try this:

```
$("#FormField_11").find("option[value='Afghanistan']").remove();
```

Comment: I triyed with this.but still its showing me 'Afghanistan' value in dropdown

$("#FormField_11").find("option[value='Afghanistan']").remove();

Comment: Can you copy here the alerted data.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

alert(jQuery('#FormField_11').html());
  

jQuery("#FormField_11").find("option[value='Afghanistan']").remove();  

  

});
</script>

Comment: i mean what message do you get in the alert box?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works. So I'm taking a wild guess that you probably have leading/trailing spaces in the 'Afghanistan' option.

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfSHP/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to remove by text of drop down instead of value. [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqvpG/)

To delete by text

```
<select id="FormField_11">
    <option value="foo">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="bar">China</option>
</select>   

jQuery("#FormField_11 option").each(function(){
   if($(this).text() == "Afghanistan")
       $(this).remove();       
});​
```